# Run html code inside PHP if

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this PHP code and I want it so  that I can run some HTMl code inside my PHP if statement.

```
 if ($_GET['report'] == "success")
    {

    RUN HTML CODE HERE

    } else if ($_GET['report'] == "fail") {

    echo 'Error';


      }
```

Html Code:

```
      <li>
       <div class="notification success">
        <p>Success Notification</p>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="close">&times;</a>
        </div> 
      </li>
```

Comment: You don't "run" html code. Html is a markup language, it defines what your website (in this case) looks like. You run php/javascript which generates html most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can close your php code, write the HTML, then open your php code again. Here's an example:

```
<?php
    $some_var = "something";
    if( true ) {
?>
    <div>Some HTML here</div>

<?php } else { ?>

    <div>Some other HTML</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Anyone care to elaborate on the downvotes? There's some "gaming" going on here...

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
if ($_GET['report'] == "success") {
    ?>
    <li>
        <div class="notification success">
            <p>Success Notification</p>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="close">&times;</a>
        </div>
    </li> 
    <?php
} elseif ($_GET['report'] == "fail") {
    echo 'Error';
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is cleaner

```
if ($_GET['report'] == "success")
{
    echo file_get_contents("templates/my_html_file.html");
}
else if ($_GET['report'] == "fail")
{
    echo 'Error';
}
```

**templates/my_html_file.html:**

```
<li>
    <div class="notification success">
        <p>Success Notification</p>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div> 
</li>
```